# Calculate the probability that there is no crisis in a ten-year period, to 2 significant digits.

Tags: probability, dice

This question is a tutorial question of a Statistics module that I have to take as part of my university graduation requirements.

--

A game about the impact of climate change on human life uses ten independent rolls of a fair die to simulate the weather for ten years. If the die shows one spot or six spots, then there is a crisis.

(a) Calculate the probability that there is no crisis in a ten-year period, to 2 significant digits.

(b) The quality of life increases by 10 points if there is no crisis in a ten-year period, and decreases by 2 points otherwise. Calculate the average amount by which the quality of life increases after ten years. Interpret this number in terms of a large number of worlds independently controlled by this game.

--

Proposed solution based on my understanding:

P(2,3,4,5) = 1/6 + 1/6 +  1/6 +  1/6 =  4/6

P(no crisis) = (4/6)^10
            = 0.017.

May I know if the first part of my answer to the question is correct?

Also, assuming the answer above is correct, am I right to say that according to the complement rule, 
P(crisis) = 1 - 0.017 ?

Comment: Your approach is right.  complement of (No Crisis) => at least one crisis.

Comment: @karakfa Well here comes the confusion that I face. If I were to calculate P(crisis) the same way as I did for P(no crisis) without the complement rule, it would be

P(1, 6) = 1/6 + 1/6 = 2/6
P(crisis) = (2/6)^10 = 1/59049
which is not the same as 1-0.017.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Or is 1/59049 the probability of all 10 years experiencing a crisis?

Comment: No, this is computing all years as crisis.  You should compute sum of exactly 1 crisis, exactly 2 crisis, exactly 3 crisis.. etc.